# javascript file is not enqueing

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I'm working on a custom wordpress theme. The js file is in `wp-content/theme/custom-theme/js/bootstrap.min.js`. I'm not able to load this on page while I can load the custom CSS file. My code is:

```
function test_styles(){

    /* add style */
    wp_enqueue_style('custom',get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css');

    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_styles');


function test_scripts(){

     /* add script */
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), true);  

    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_scripts')
```

The functions are in php tags and in `functions.php` file.
Thanks in advance. Help please.

Comment: You've verified that no script tag is inserted in source? Does your theme call `wp_footer()`?

Comment: Yes, in footer.php. It calls  wp_footer();

Comment: To be clear, your CSS is loaded but the JS is not?

Answer (score 1):

Using your code as-is enqueue works.

Although your arguments are a little off. The `true` you are supplying to load script in footer (I presume) is actually getting fed into a version argument. So if you are looking for it in the footer with this code it is de-facto loading in the header.

Comment: Yes - was just about to recommend adding a version argument to fill out the set and ensure the true boolean was read for footer.  Well put Rarst.

Comment: Okay, I get it. But even after this:                                                              `function test_scripts(){
  
   /* add script */
  wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), false, true);  

  }

  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_scripts')`

Comment: but even after this according to:                               `wp_enqueue_script ( string $handle, string|bool $src = false, array $deps = array(), string|bool $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )`                                                                                                         which is given on - [link]https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/[link]. It's not loading.

Comment: As I said simply copy/pasting your code into my dev install works. If you have a problem it's not with this part of it.